# Azure DevOps pipeline execution with user interface

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I would need your help in getting some information regarding my current requirement. As, I am working on creating multiple profile for different clients. For. e.g. I have 5 clients and all of them are on different versions of application and I want each client to have select option like a UI based interface and based on the client selection and submission the pipeline will than execute tasks accordingly.

Is there a any separate tool for Azure DevOps to provide GUI for end client or any Azure DevOps widget available?

Thank you for all your help

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can set [runtime parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script) at the beginning of a YAML, for example:

```
parameters:
- name: client
  displayName: clientSelection
  type: string
  default: ''
  values:
  - clientA
  - clientB
  - clientC
  - clientD
  - clientE
```

The effect when you click to run the pipeline:

[image]

[image]

Then we can [set the condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for the stages/jobs/tasks, for example:

```
jobs:
  - job: A
    steps:
    - script: echo something
    condition: eq('${{ parameters.client }}', 'clientA')
```

In this way, the corresponding job will be run according to the client selection.